# How does Mei Chang age all of a sudden at the end of FMA: Brotherhood?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

As Mei Chang was introduced in *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*, she was depicted as a small child. But at the end, when she settles down with Alphonse Elric, she grows a lot more than the other characters.

Why is that so?

Comment: Is there any reason she *shouldn't* be able to grow at a different rate than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the image in the credits of the last episode, bear in mind it isn't revealed how many years into the future it is (it is likely even later than the 2 year time-skip mentioned) which is why she might appear older. This is evident as Ed and Winry are holding 2 babies (the elder looking around 3, I would say).

Wikia only says "After a two-year time skip, Alphonse prepares to travel to Xing in order to study Alkahestry with Mei. In the epilogue, she is seen in the new Elric family picture."

Amino mentions that she is around 10 at the start of the anime, and around 13 after the time skip.

Therefore, it is difficult to answer your question because we don't know how much time has passed since the end of FMAB, but **it is likely she would be around 15-16 in that image**, if not even older, as both Ed and Al go to the West and East, meaning these babies wouldn't have been born right after the end of the anime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's bc like you know  how in the beginning she was 10 from the start and I think Edward was 14 and al was 13  and then you know how the end she is 13 and ya so maybe it took some time years to get back xing probably would've taken like 4 to 3 years and ig I'm pretty sure it was 4 yrs after when they went to xing and ment mei

Comment: Welcome to [Anime & Manga!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) It's better for the OP and everyone who comes across this answer to have an easy time reading, so I would suggest [*editing*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/65319/edit) your answer for better formatting, such as grammar, spelling, spacing, etc. It is also better to include relevant sources and citations in your answer.